# How to simulate voting in GitHub's Issues 2.0 Tracker

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I'm considering moving my open-source project [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) from Google Code to GitHub.

One of the features I really like in Google Code's Issue Tracker is the **ability to vote** and **sort issues by the number of votes**. This has allowed me to get a good feel of where current pain points lie and what the community feels needs attention or further work.

How can I achieve something similar on GitHub? Is there a way to maintain a democratic approach to Issue Tracking?

Comment: Hm, you could apply for a free JIRA and connect it to github, couldn't you?

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in ability to do so. Technically speaking, you can only manage issues by

- assignee
- tags (called labels at github)
- milestones

While you can define label systems for lots of differentation criteria like

- bug/feature request/...
- prio high/low/...
- status verified/unverified

it is simply not possible to have something that accumulates votes. So typically you will see "+1" postings as in good old mailing lists. I've seen people using external voting systems (like Google moderator) for issues on github, but that doesn't make a good user experience either.

Comment: And surprisingly they don't even make the number of watchers visible like Google Code does.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use a third-party system that integrates with GitHub, you can try [GitPoll](http://poll.gitrun.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Since (at least) 2019, you can now sort issues using `sort:reactions-+1-desc`